# Pass fancytree data as JSON data

Tags: json, generic-handler, fancytree

I want to pass the data from a fancytree to a generic handler so that I can save it for future use.

If I use this code:

```
function SaveTree() {
    var tree = $('#TopTree').fancytree("getTree");
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "SaveTree.ashx",
        data: { 'treeData': tree },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
}
```

Then I get the following error from jquery.js:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Argument not optional
```

I have also tried:

```
var tree = $('#TopTree').fancytree("getTree").rootNode.children;
```

This gives the same error. I understand it is because 'tree' is not JSON. How can I convert the data to a JSON object?

EDIT:

If I use this code:

```
function SaveTree() {
    var data = [];
    var tree = $('#TopTree').fancytree("getTree").rootNode.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        data.push(tree[i].title)
    }
    data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "SaveTree.ashx",
        data: { 'treeData': data },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
}
```

I can get it to accomplish what I need, but is there not a built-in function for this in fancytree?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I don't really know a lot about FancyTree; however, I did some investigation and found this page http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-api.html.

Try the tree.ToDict() option to see if that is what you're looking for.

This is the source code.

```
  // Convert the whole tree into an dictionary
  var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");
  var d = tree.toDict(true);
  alert(JSON.stringify(d));
```